# Не выводит результат в VS Code на Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, powershell

Пример кода брал из книги, код работает правильно в IDLE, но VSC выдает ошибку:

```py
def search4vowels (word):
    """Выводит гласный во введенном коде"""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    found = vowels.intersection(set(word))
    for vowel in found:
        print (vowel)
```

Ошибка, которую выдает:

```
search4vowels : Имя "search4vowels" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, 
после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ search4vowels ('eqewtryruumjh')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (search4vowels:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Вы функцию пытаетесь через Powershell запустить. А нужно сначала python запустить, в нем импортировать ваш модуль, потом уже вызывать функцию.

Comment: А не подскажете как запустить через phyton и импортировать модуль?

Comment: В том же powershell пишите python, потом пишите `import имя_файла` (где имя_файла - имя вашего модуля без расширения), потом уже запускаете `search4vowels ('eqewtryruumjh')`